# Extending link-to

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a custom `link-to` helper that will conditionally add `query-params` depending on the presence of a property. Right now, I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`. I've traced that to the line `var options = parameters.options` in the function `resolvedParams`.

Here's my code:

In `app/components/foo-link.js`:

```
export default Ember.LinkView.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
  }
});
```

In the template:

```
{{foo-link title='Bar' hrefBinding='bar'}}
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Is this even the correct approach? I've already extended `SelectView`'s like this, so I'm not sure why this is so difficult.

I'm using Ember CLI version 0.1.5.

Comment: why are you extending a view in a component?

Comment: Because I'm a silly person who couldn't get any of the other extended views to work when I put them in the views folder. I'm pretty new to Ember, and I had managed to extend the `select` view using a similar approach. Maybe I should submit a question that asks why it doesn't recognize views placed in the views folder.